# Intermittent 'Connection reset by peer' error with gRPC on AWS production environment

Tags: php, laravel, go, grpc

I'm experiencing an intermittent error in my production environment, where a Go gRPC server communicates with a PHP/Laravel gRPC client. This issue does not occur in the development environment. The production environment differs in that it's deployed across three AWS instances.

Error Message:
**gRPC call failed: recvmsg:Connection reset by peer**

Go gRPC Server Code:

```
func RunGrpcServer() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8089")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot create listener : %s", err)
    }

    serverRegistrar := grpc.NewServer()
    service := &myToysServiceServer{}

    gasgrpc.RegisterToysServiceServer(serverRegistrar, service)

    err = serverRegistrar.Serve(lis)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("impossible to server: %s", err)
    }
}
```

PHP/Laravel gRPC Client Code:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $channelCredentials = ChannelCredentials::createSsl();
        
        $this->client = new ToysServiceClient(config('grpc.grpc_url'), [
            'credentials' => $channelCredentials,
        ]);
    }
public function getToys(): RepeatedField
    {
        $request = new GetAllToysRequest();

        list($response, $status) = $this->client->GetAllToys(
            $request,
            [],
            ['timeout' => $this->timeout]
        )->wait();

        if ($status->code !== \Grpc\STATUS_OK) {
            throw new \Exception("gRPC call failed: " . $status->details);
        }

        return $response->getToysHistories();
    }
```

I've verified that the network settings and firewall rules are consistent between environments. What might be causing these intermittent 'Connection reset by peer' errors in the AWS production environment?